# does keyset and values have same order in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

as I know keyset() doesn't guarantee any particular order, however does values() get same order as keyset()?
how about linkedhashmap? seems it can provide a consistent order keyset, assume that it also get a same order values()?

Answer (score 2):

There are absolutely no promises about order in hash tables.

Comment: Is the `KeySet`/`ValueSet` of a `HashMap` a `HashTable`? I thought this was a specially implemented type. The keys/values are not copied as far as I know, they simply query the `HashMap` in a special way.

Comment: No, they aren't hashtables. But you're asking whether their order is related to each other. And the answer is the same as for other aspects of ordering in the hashtable: there is no promise of this in the documentation, therefore you can't count on it. Even if they were in parallel this week, they might not be next time a Java fix comes out. As@GiovanniBotta says, the right answer is to use idioms that work without counting on this relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to iterate through any java `Map` is to use the idiom:

```
for(Map.Entry<K,V> e : map.entrySet()){
  K theKey = e.getKey();
  V theValue = e.getValue();
  // do something with them!
}
```

This idiom makes the question irrelevant as you are going through entries in the map in the form of key, value pairs.

As already noted, there is no order guarantees except for `SortedMap`s or `LinkedHashMap` and the like. If you have a total ordering on your keys, use a `SortedMap`: always model your problem explicitly.